# Sending cookies to a server from Background script in chrome extension?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to send cookies back to my server from my chrome extension..Getting the cookies is working however when I try and execute an AJAX it doesn't seem to execute? any ideas? Code below:

backgroundscript.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(res, sender, sendResponse){
 GetMyCookies(function(response){
  alert(response.value)
  $.ajax({
    url:     "https://my-server", 
    method: "post",
    data: {response}
    })
    .done(function(res){
    alert("done")
    })
  })
  })


function GetMyCookies (callback){
  chrome.cookies.get({ url: 'https://www.examplesite.com/', name: 'cookie1' },    function(cookie){
    callback(cookie)
  })
}
```

UPDATE: New code below, this sends to the server, however it is received as 'undefined'. It looks like its an associative array as when I alert(params) i get [object Object]? Any ideas?

background.js

```
 chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(res, sender, sendResponse){
  GetMyCookies(function(response){
   var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
   var url = "https://my-server";
   var params = response.value;
   http.open("POST", url, true);
   http.send(params)
   alert(params)
  })
})


function GetMyCookies (callback){
chrome.cookies.get({ url: 'https://www.example.com/', name: 'cookie1'},    function(cookie){
    callback(cookie)
  })
}
```

Comment: Obvious question: do you have jQuery included? Can you add your manifest?

Comment: Updated my question @Xan

Comment: Doesn't look like you can use `send` this way: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#send()

Comment: It looks like its because its async.. whats the best way to solve this?

Comment: Does this code run?  It looks like you're missing some semicolons.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please try using

```
alert(JSON.stringify(params));
```

BTW, you should add semicolons after every statement in JavaScript.